# Array splice with unexpected results

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to understand [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

> deleteCount: An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove.

Ok. Seems straightforward. I want to remove the last 4 objects in the array. I hope that's the same as elements?

```
arr.splice(<start>, deleteCount<how-many-to-remove>):


// {0 - 8} is an example of object position
let obArr = [{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}]

// Start from the last and remove four:
obArr.splice(-1, 4)

console.log(obArr) // not expected.

console.log(obArr) // expected: [{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}]
```

Comment: Don't use splice at all, it is considered a bad practice. Instead use array.slice and it's not python so -1 won't work in slice as well.

Comment: Would you care to add another way instead of splice?

Comment: @Zydnar why do say `-1 won't work in slice`?

Comment: I assumed `-1` means the "last" as indexOf?

Comment: @MarkMeyer it's not what I mean, it will simply work the same way, but it won't change `obArr` so it's not what OP wants.

Comment: @Sylar About using slice instead of splice - it's only cosmetic, sometimes it means variable mutation before developer wants it, so just use splice with caution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code starts at the last item and tries to remove four values *after* the last item. But there aren't four values after the last item. If you want to remove four from the end start earlier in the array:

```js
let obArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

// Start from the 4th last and remove four:
obArr.splice(-4, 4)

console.log(obArr)
```

Comment: Readability is now understandable "Start from the 4th last and remove four". Many thanks